# Gray desktop after updating XFCE on Xubuntu

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, xubuntu, ppa, xfce

Lately, I've been trying to run multiple monitors on Xubuntu without having them cloned. On the internet, I found some instructions to do that which basically required me to add a PPA in order to upgrade XFCE to 4.12. I added the PPA:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.12`

then upgraded:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

However, after a reboot, I noticed that my desktop background went completely gray and when I move windows it changes (clearly some kind of an UI glitch). Now, I instantly `ppa-purge`'d the PPA, but the problem remains. My current XFCE version is 4.8 (at least that's what `xfce4-about` says). By the way, during the installation of the PPA I saw the nvidia driver is also being reloaded, so I'm not sure, could that be the problem, and if so: how do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent hours trying to upgrade and downgrade packages, but the solution appears to have been a lot simpler than that. While researching, I found this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266271/error-parsing-gtk-icon-sizes-string-desktop-grey-with-no-icons). The specific answer that helped is this [one](https://askubuntu.com/a/274163/251913). All I did was:

```
sudo apt-get install xfdesktop4
```

and after a reboot, the icons and wallpaper appeared on my desktop. I hope this will be helpful for users experiencing the same problem in the future. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me just a few days ago on xenial (16.04). Background was black though. No icons anywhere and some applications didn't at all (I tested Evince and Synaptic). Probably after a upgrade?

Anyways, I did try to clean session cache but it didn't help. but then i reinstalled xfdesktop4 and I got it back. A bit simpler than the whole upgrading business. Though of course that applied to a different version.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xfdesktop4
```

Did the trick for me. After reboot.